# How to save special character name like Āhualoa in mysql using hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I need to save a us country city name which has some special character.

I am using Spring hibernate and using save method of hibernate to persist and object.

when I pass string Āhualoa  while saving .it save ?hualoa in mysql db.

Comment: Set the collation of your DB to be `UTF-8`.

Comment: Additionally you should add the character encoding to your JDBC connection string. eg: `dataSource.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/databasename?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8`